# Why fonts loaded using CoreText (CTFont) behave different than loaded using AppKit (NSFont)?

Tags: fonts, nsattributedstring, core-text, fontmetrics, nsfont

I tried to load font using `CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor()` and it behaves differently than loaded using `NSFont()`. Let's say the goal is to load font using `CoreText` that is exactly the same as using `AppKit`.

### NSTextField

If I use them in `NSTextField` text offsets and rendering do not match.

```swift
let familyName = "Helvetica"
let fontSize: CGFloat = 30
let string = "Hello, World! gÖ,|#"

// Load font using AppKit
let font1 = NSFont(name: familyName, size: fontSize)!

// Load font using CoreText API
let font2 = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes([
    kCTFontFamilyNameAttribute: familyName,
    kCTFontSizeAttribute: fontSize,
] as [CFString : Any] as CFDictionary), 0, nil) as NSFont

// Setup text fields

let field1 = NSTextField()
let field2 = NSTextField()
field1.setAsLabel()
field2.setAsLabel()
field1.font = font1
field2.font = font2
field1.stringValue = string
field2.stringValue = string
```

[NSTextField result preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NduJK.png)

### NSAttributedString

If I use them in `NSAttributedString` bounding box height of text is different:

```swift
let bounds1 = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [
    .font: font1
]).boundingRect(with: .infinity)

let bounds2 = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [
    .font: font2
]).boundingRect(with: .infinity)

print(bounds1) // Prints: (0.0, -7.0, 252.3486328125, 37.0)
print(bounds2) // Prints: (0.0, -7.0, 252.3486328125, 31.0)
```

---

### Investigation

I compared fonts, font attributes, traits, feature settings, even binary font tables but I didn't find any difference. It seems like there is something inside that alters behaviour.

I found that if I add .`usesDeviceMetrics` option to `NSAttributedString` bounds getter, it returns the same result but also completely different frame.

```swift
let bounds1 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, World! gÖ,|#", attributes: [.font: font1]).boundingRect(with: .infinity, options: [.usesDeviceMetrics])
let bounds2 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, World! gÖ,|#", attributes: [.font: font2]).boundingRect(with: .infinity, options: [.usesDeviceMetrics])

print(bounds1) // Prints: (2.3583984375, -6.6357421875, 249.9609375, 33.837890625)
print(bounds2) // Prints: (2.3583984375, -6.6357421875, 249.9609375, 33.837890625)
```

---

### Question

***How to load a font using CoreText in a way that `NSFont` does?***

*Minor question: Why does `NSTextField` set it's frame origin to `-2.0`?*

---

Just extensions I used in code above:

```swift
extension CGSize {
    public static var infinity: Self {
        .init(width: CGFloat.infinity, height: CGFloat.infinity)
    }
}

extension NSTextField {
    func setAsLabel() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        isBezeled = false
        isBordered = false
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = false
        drawsBackground = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor question question: what is the default frame and which property change changes the frame?

Comment: If I emplace `NSTextField` into `NSWindow.contentView` with 4 constraints equal top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints without any constant, `NSTextField` has intrinsic content size and `origin.x = -2.0`. It somehow fools constraint engine.

Comment: Weird, I tried your code and I get bounding box height 36 and 30 in Swift, 36 and 36 in Objective-C.

Comment: Is it the font or `NSTextField` that behaves differently? I tried multiple lines in an editable text field and it looks like it's `NSTextField`.

Comment: I also tried to use the fonts in `NSAttributedString` (see above) which is not related to `NSTextField` and bounds also differ. I guess it is the font or some special handling `NSFont` inside `NS` classes.